# Swift: Replicate Banking Mobile Check Deposit Camera Functionality

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Bank of America (as I am sure other banking apps do) allows users to deposit bank checks by taking photos of the front and back.  But what is pretty interesting is that the camera recognizes when the phone is still, focused on a document, and the proper distance from it.

I already have the functionality of taking photos with a `UIImagePickerController` working perfectly (and saving to `Core Data`, populating a `UITableViewController`, etc.), but would love to be able to allow the camera to do the same as Bank of America does.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction recreate these capabilities?

To my understanding, what they are doing really breaks down into the following:

1. know when the camera is still
2. know when the text on the check/paper is visible (in other words, in focus and good lighting)
3. know when the check/paper is a particular distance from the camera

Comment: I have the similar interest. What is UIImagePickerController?

Comment: @Jeb50 It allows you to take (with your camera) or pick (from your photo library) a photo https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score -1):

Many, if not all bank apps leverage a 3rd party framework for that. So you could go that route, or you can start you researching looking over I believe it's MDLCamera docs to see what's available to you vs. what you have to write.